# nhibernate using the same sqlparameter with Expression.Disjunction()

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

I have a search method as below. I want user search text to be splitted and searched over some columns of different tables.

```
 string[] searchedTexts = null;

        if(searchText!=null)
           searchedTexts = searchText.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        WebsitePage page = null;
        Account account = null;
        AccountLogin login = null;
        Author author = null;
        var query = Session.QueryOver<WebsitePage>(() => page).Where(() => page.Status == WebsitePageStatus.Online).Left
            .JoinQueryOver<Author>(x => x.Blogger, () => author).Left
            .JoinQueryOver<Account>(x => x.AccountInfo, () => account).Left
            .JoinQueryOver<AccountLogin>(x => x.Logins, () => login);


        if (searchedTexts != null)
        {
            var disconjaction = Expression.Disjunction();
            foreach (var text in searchedTexts)
            {
                disconjaction.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Property(() => page.Title), text, MatchMode.Anywhere));
                disconjaction.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Property(() => page.Body), text, MatchMode.Anywhere));
                disconjaction.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Property(() => page.TagCommaSeperated), text, MatchMode.Anywhere));
                disconjaction.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Property(() => account.FirstName), text, MatchMode.Anywhere));
                disconjaction.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Property(() => account.LastName), text, MatchMode.Anywhere));                    
                disconjaction.Add(Expression.Like(Projections.Property<AccountLogin>(x => x.UserName), text, MatchMode.Anywhere)); 
            }



            query.And(disconjaction);
        }



        return query.List();
```

As you can see in  Expression.Like() method I used the same parameter. After execution, nhibernate add different parameter for each "Like" expression like:

```
@p1=N'%test%',@p2=N'%test%',@p3=N'%test%',@p4=N'%search%',@p5=N'%search%',@p6=N'%search%'
```

In each loop of foreach , I want to use one sqlparameter with all 6 "Like" expression.
Is it possible ?

Comment: NHibernate doesn't know that you pass the value of the same variable in your code. Does the duplication matter much?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not possible.

I don't think it matters either, unless you are interested in avoiding the hard-limit of 2100 parameters in TSQL.